# What is heroku database copy?

Tags: heroku, database-backups, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

I messed up with my database and would like to do a rollback. Since I am using Heroku Postgress Hobby Basic plan which doesn't support automatic backups, there is no any backup which I can restore to.

```
heroku pg:backups --app heroku-app-name
```

This command gives me following result:

```
=== Backups
No backups. Capture one with heroku pg:backups:capture

=== Restores
No restores found. Use heroku pg:backups:restore to restore a backup

=== Copies
ID    Started at           Status                         Size    From          To
────  ───────────────────  ─────────────────────────────  ──────  ─────────  ─────────
c002  2022-06-09 18:53:16  Completed 2022-06-09 18:53:39  3.12MB  From Name  Target Na
c001  2020-05-27 21:47:47  Completed 2020-05-27 21:48:13  3.12MB  DATABASE   BLUE
```

I would like to know what are these Copies, specifically what does the copy `c002` stand for, does it contain any data and if it can downloaded/used as some kind of a backup.